# readLine() returns null even though file has content

Tags: java, csv, file-io, null, readline

The numberOfFields() method is supposed to find out how many columns exist in a particular row of a csv file. I'm expecting 7 but my output comes out to be 0; which is what I've initialized cols as. So I used system.out.println() inside the while loop and I  figured out that the while loop isn't being entered. My file has plenty of lines of text so I don't understand why readLine() returns null. Not sure where else I could be wrong.

```
public class CSVReader {

    public BufferedReader bR1;

    public CSVReader(String fileName) throws IOException {
        bR1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    }


    public int numberOfFields(int row) throws IOException {
        int rows = 1;
        while (rows < row) {
            bR1.readLine();
            rows++;
        }
        int cols = 0;

        String line;
        while ((line=bR1.readLine()) != null) {
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");
            while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
                st.nextToken();
                cols++;
            }
        }
        return cols;
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, it depends on how you are calling your `numberOfFields` method. What is the value for `row`? Because if you skip through the whole csv file in the first while loop, there is no rows left for the reader to read in the second while loop. You should look into this behavior and maybe explain what you are trying to achieve with the first loop.

Comment: If you call `numberOfFields()` more than once, all but the first call will fail, since `bR1` is no longer positioned at the beginning of the file. It is actually positioned at the end of the file, since that where the first call left the reader.

Comment: @Andreas I am, in fact, calling this, and another method (numberOfRows() ) more than once and I believe you figured out the issue. Right now, the pointer is as the end of the file after having called numberOfRows() to find out the number of rows in the file. Is there a way to way to reposition the pointer to the beginning of the file?

Comment: @maloomeister the call was: numberOfFields(10); where I wish to find out the number of fields in the 10th row. The purpose of the first while loop (rows<row) is to position my pointer to the row right before the row that I need to find the number of fields of, so I can then use stringTokenizer. Also, the file has 214 rows so there should not be any issue of no rows being left to read.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, there may be two reason :

1. the parameter `row` you give exceed the line number of the file.
2. your fileName is wrong.

I suggest you add `System.out.println(bR1.readLine)` in the first while loop to see what happend.

Comment: In my opinion, the reason is that `numberOfFields()` is called more than once.

Comment: So I did what you suggested and I got null as output. But I think that is because of what Andreas mentioned. After calling a method to find out the number of rows, my pointer is now at the end of the file and hence, the null. Is there a way to reposition the pointer to the beginning of the file?

Comment: BufferedReader.mark(int) and BufferedReader.reset() can do this.@eva

Answer (score 0):

An `InputStream` can only be read once.

If you call `numberOfFields()` more than once, all but the first call will fail, since `bR1` is no longer positioned at the beginning of the file. It is actually positioned at the end of the file, since that where the first call left the reader.

Instead of opening the stream in the constructor, have each method open their own stream.

In the following, these issues have been fixed:

- Using try-with-resources for correctly handling the closing of the stream.

  Try-with-resources was added in Java 7, so unless you're running on ancient versions of Java, there is absolutely no good reason to use it.
- Changed code to only count the columns of the request row, not the columns of all remaining rows.
- Use of `StringTokenizer` has been replaced by regex. As the javadoc of `StringTokenizer` says:

  > **`StringTokenizer` is a legacy class** that is retained for compatibility reasons although its **use is discouraged** in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality **use the `split` method of `String`** or the `java.util.regex` package instead.

```java
public class CSVReader {

    public final String fileName;

    public CSVReader(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    public int numberOfFields(int row) throws IOException {
        try (BufferedReader bR1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(this.fileName))) {
            // Skip row-1 rows
            for (int rows = 1; rows < row; rows++) {
                bR1.readLine();
            }
            
            // Count number of columns in next line, if available
            String line = bR1.readLine();
            return (line == null ? 0 : line.split(",", -1).length);
        }
    }
```